# Excluding an element in an array using JsonDeserializer in gson

Tags: java, json, kotlin, gson

I have an example json object

```json
{
    id: 10,
    name: "Hello World",
    components: [
        {
            id: 1,
            type: "FRAME"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            type: "DEFAULT"
        }
    ]
}
```

And JsonDeserializer but only for Component objects

```kotlin
class ComponentDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Component> {
    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement,
        typeOfT: Type,
        context: JsonDeserializationContext
    ): Component {
        val componentObject = json.asJsonObject
        
        val id = componentObject.get("id").asInt
        val type = componentObject.get("type").asString
        
        return Component(
            id = id,
            type = type
        )
    }
}
```

Can I somehow exclude components that have the type "DEFAULT" from the array without writing a deserializer for the entire json? I'd like something like "return null" and then the "components" array has one less element

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out,
I can just deserialize list of components:

For future generations:
Add registerTypeAdapter to gson builder

```kotlin
val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(object : TypeToken<MutableList<Component>>() {}.type, ComponentsDeserializer())
        .create()
```

And set appropriate type for JsonDeserializer

```kotlin
class ComponentsDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<List<Component>> {
    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement,
        typeOfT: Type,
        context: JsonDeserializationContext
    ): List<Component> {
        /* filter list... */
    }
}
```